# How to convert machine code to assembly code?

Tags: pascal

Please suggest me How to convert machine code to assembly code? excluding intel reference manual and dos debugger method?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disassembler

Answer (score 1):

You can use any debugger, such as gdb, or any disassembler, such as IDA Pro Advanced.

There also are opensource ones, such as Agner Fog's objtool.

IDA Pro Advanced also has the Hexrays plugin, with which you can decompile code.

Answer (score 0):

look at this thread :

[How might I convert Intel 80386 Machine Code to Assembly Language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173568/how-might-i-convert-intel-80386-machine-code-to-assembly-language)